# Exclude columns on Update Linq to entity

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to store update-date and create-date for all records.

I add Override for SaveChanges method the Problem when I update a record the CreatedDate become null. so my question is, on update how can I keep the CreatedDate without changes.

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        try
        {
            var changeSet = ChangeTracker.Entries();
            dynamic obj;
            if (changeSet != null)
            {
                foreach (var entry in changeSet.Where(c => c.State == EntityState.Added))
                {
                    obj = entry.Entity;
                    obj.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                }
                foreach (var entry in changeSet.Where(c => c.State == EntityState.Modified))
                {
                    obj = entry.Entity;
                    obj.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: General suggestion - why not combine those 2 loops into 1 with an if-else?

Answer (score 0):

Simple, dont pass CreateDate when you update!

```
 if (changeSet != null)
            {
                foreach (var entry in changeSet.Where(c => c.State == EntityState.Added))
                {
                    obj = entry.Entity;

                }
                foreach (var entry in changeSet.Where(c => c.State == EntityState.Modified))
                {
                    obj = entry.Entity;

                }
            }
```

Comment: @Bakri It does not matter, add a validation if the new date is there, then you pass